# gcc atomics supported types

Tags: c, gcc, atomic

This is a quote from the recent gcc manual regarding the types supported for atomic operations.

> The four non-arithmetic functions (load, store, exchange, and compare
>   exchange) all have a generic version as well. This generic version
>   works on any data type. If the data type size maps to one of the
>   integral sizes that may have lock free support, the generic version
>   utilizes the lock free built-in function. Otherwise an external call
>   is left to be resolved at run time. This external call is the same
>   format with the addition of a ‘size_t’ parameter inserted as the first
>   parameter indicating the size of the object being pointed to. All
>   objects must be the same size.

The original document is here [gcc 4.8.1](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html#_005f_005fatomic-Builtins). I assume that the hardware can only perform atomic operations on simple 32, 64 and occasionaly 128bit types. So, what happens with these generic versions of the functions that take a pointer? Only the access to the pointer can actually be atomic, right?

An additional related question is how do these atomics work in a language like java where everything is boxed? What is accessed atomically, the value or the reference?

Answer (score 1):

It is mentioned that for the generic types lock is used.